# Encoding graphics into an mpeg stream

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, mpeg

looking for an example of how to programatically encode a frame-buffer into an mpeg stream. I need this to experiment with some mpeg encoders, to see how different patterns compress.

I have a slight inclination towards Windows, although if linux gives some advantage it is not a problem.

Comment: Are you looking for libraries that will do the encoding for you or do you want to write an encoder yourself?

Comment: End result would be to optimize an existing encoder for a specific use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can turn your frame-buffer into a series of image files, you could convert them to mpeg video using [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

From the [docs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion):

> For creating a video from many images:
>
> ```
>  ffmpeg -f image2 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -r 12 -s WxH foo.avi
> ```
>
> The syntax `"foo-%03d.jpeg"` specifies to use a decimal number composed
>   of three digits padded with zeroes to express the sequence number. It
>   is the same syntax supported by the C `printf` function, but only
>   formats accepting a normal integer are suitable.

You'd want something like:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i in-%d.jpg out.mpg
```

for an mpeg stream.